# Import big mongodb bson archive > 300Mb

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, import

I've installed mongodb the next way on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

Then I've downloaded sample mongodb database:

```
wget https://atlas-education.s3.amazonaws.com/sampledata.archive
```

But I do not know how to import it on Ubuntu. I've imported it on Windows using Studio 3T application. Also, it could be done by using this application from windows if I configure authentication on my remote ubuntu server, open in firewall required port and enable binding for mongodb on 0.0.0.0 in /etc/mongod.conf.

But on Ubuntu, when I rename it to `sampledata.archive.bson` and try to import it, I get the next output with the error:

```
user@server:~/projects/mongodb_sample_db$ mongorestore sampledata.archive.bson
2023-03-02T15:21:00.155+0100    checking for collection data in sampledata.archive.bson
2023-03-02T15:21:00.155+0100    restoring to existing collection test.sampledata.archive without dropping
2023-03-02T15:21:00.155+0100    restoring test.sampledata.archive from sampledata.archive.bson
2023-03-02T15:21:00.201+0100    finished restoring test.sampledata.archive (0 documents, 0 failures)
2023-03-02T15:21:00.201+0100    Failed: test.sampledata.archive: error restoring from sampledata.archive.bson: reading bson input: invalid BSONSize: -2120621459 bytes is less than 5 bytes
2023-03-02T15:21:00.201+0100    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

The possible cause of the error: the file size is too big:

```
4983289 -rw-rw-r--  1 user user 305M Mar 10  2022 sampledata.archive.bson
```

How can I import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [The MongoDB Atlas Sample Datasets](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/atlas-sample-datasets/)

For me it works:

```
mongorestore.exe --uri="mongodb://admin:*****@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin" --archive=sampledata.archive

2023-03-03T10:50:50.768+0100    preparing collections to restore from
...
2023-03-03T10:51:03.840+0100    424065 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Comment: It seems it works, thank you. It is better do not put password between `mongodb://admin:` and `@localhost:...` because it will be visible in history and you need to remove it from there.

Comment: The password would be also visible in `ps`, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-2768 If you are concerned about security I suggest option [--config](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#std-option-mongorestore.--config)

Comment: Process of importing through mongorestore in `ps` looks like:

Comment: `user 3902941  6.1  0.8 1385196 68652 pts/0   Sl+  22:32   0:00 mongorestore --uri=mongodb://mongouser@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin --archive=/home/user/projects/mongodb_sample_db/sampledata.archive.bson`

Comment: So no password visible if I do not specify it in uri